# Why is this.name undefined?

Tags: javascript, events

Why does `this.name` returns me undefined?

```
function EventEmitter() {
  var events = {};
  this.name = "Google"
  this.on = function(name, fn) {
    events[name] = events[name] || [];
    events[name].push(fn);
  }
  this.trigger = function(name, args) {
    events[name] = events[name] || [];
    args = args || [];
    events[name].forEach(function(fn) {
      fn.apply(this, args);
    });
  }
}

var my_event_emitter = new EventEmitter();
my_event_emitter.on('curtain_dropped', function() {
  console.log(this.name);
});
my_event_emitter.trigger('curtain_dropped', [true]);
```

When i am calling `fn.apply(this, args)` is the `this` not the instance of `EventEmitter` which is `my_event_emitter`?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

forEach has its own context. Use one of the 3 ways to bind the new context such as:

```
events[name].forEach(function(fn) {
  fn.apply(this, args);
}.bind(this));
```

You can also pass (as the 2 arg to forEach) the context. The arguments to the callback are (value, index, originalArray, context);

```
events[name].forEach(function(fn) {
  fn.apply(this, args);
},this);
```

Comment: Sometimes `bind` isn't the best option. Closures have better performance than `bind`. Anyway, it's a possible approach and it'll work!

Comment: Can you just show me on how to pass the context as 4th argument by modifying the example.

Comment: One final question, why does the function execute in the global context and not in the EventEmitter context? Is there any advantage and specific reason behind that.

Comment: Internally, `forEach` won't "bind" to a specific context unless you tell it to.

Answer (score 2):

No; `this` is the context in which your `forEach` callback was invoked.
By default, that's the global object.

You need to pass a second parameter to `forEach()` to tell it what `this` should be in its callback.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the following code line:

```
events[name].forEach(function(fn) {
  fn.apply(this, args);
});
```

When you call `apply`, you're giving the wrong `this` reference, since you're inside the `forEach` closure.

If you want to provide the `EventEmitter` instance reference on `this`, you'll need to store it in a variable and use it inside the closure:

```
function EventEmitter() {
  var events = {};
  var that = this; // <-- Current instance reference!
  this.name = "Google"
  this.on = function(name, fn) {
    events[name] = events[name] || [];
    events[name].push(fn);
  }
  this.trigger = function(name, args) {
    events[name] = events[name] || [];
    args = args || [];
    events[name].forEach(function(fn) {
      fn.apply(that, args); // Provide "that" instead of "this"
    });
  }
}
```